# Shadow DOMing a whole page. What are the benefits and drawbacks?

Tags: shadow-dom

I'm currently learning about web components and Shadow DOM, and the first thing that popped into my head was "this seems like it would break my url highlighting extension if applied too liberally."  My understanding of the Shadow DOM is incomplete, but if it's supposed to be a [scope in which the rest of the pages styling does not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972011/shadow-dom-in-html), then it seems only natural that plugins and extensions which style specific elements would be rendered useless within that scope.

This is just one example of what might happen if a developer wrapped their entire site in a web component (Shadow DOMed it), and the benefit might be that their site is safe from extensions meddling with it, and a drawback might be that users meddling extensions don't work on that site.

But what are some other benefits and drawbacks?  Are there any good reasons I should start Shadow DOMing my sites?  Are there good reasons to not?

EDIT:  I just read that there is a `closed` mode for shadow DOMs which makes them uneditable.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933432/4808079

EDIT: There is a form of hack that allows for entry to `closed` Shadow DOMs, but it may only be applicable in rare cases https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af

Comment: The benefits and drawbacks will be the same: extensions won't see the shadow dom content.